# Matrix minus matrix in Python/Numpy

Tags: python, numpy

I am confused about the matrix minus matrix in Numpy. Given a vector v of size 10 by 1 and a matrix X of size 10 by 20. Why can we compute v-X in Python? What does this result mean?

For example, v=[1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4,1,2]. We cannot compute v-X. But we can compute v-X if we coded as follows:

```
v.reshape((10,1))
X-v
```

Comment: Please include more details in your question. It still leaves room for speculation of what you're doing. How are you building your vectors/arrays. Include a minimal example.

Comment: What is the code you have? What is the output?

Comment: @luk2302 I have a data set. I give one example.

Comment: Do you use numpy?

Comment: Your edit is still very conservative. Produce a well documented question first. Only then people can help you.

Comment: @Corralien Yes. I use numpy.

Comment: You have to share more details, the question is not clear

Comment: For a simple input produce the expect outcome to ensure everyone understand what you want.

Comment: What do you mean by `matrix`? matrix and array are not the same things

Comment: The key is `broadcasting`, https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.broadcasting.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make 2 smaller arrays:

```
In [128]: x = np.arange(6).reshape(2,3)
In [129]: x
Out[129]: 
array([[0, 1, 2],
       [3, 4, 5]])
In [130]: v = np.array([10,20])
```

Can't subtract:

```
In [131]: x-v
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<ipython-input-131-e16f27714407>", line 1, in <module>
    x-v
ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (2,3) (2,)
```

The error explains why.  But change the (2,) to (2,1):

```
In [132]: v[:,None]
Out[132]: 
array([[10],
       [20]])
In [133]: x-v[:,None]
Out[133]: 
array([[-10,  -9,  -8],
       [-17, -16, -15]])
```

or the action may standout better if we add:

```
In [134]: x+v[:,None]
Out[134]: 
array([[10, 11, 12],
       [23, 24, 25]])
```

The (2,3) array and (2,1) do work together, by the basic rules of `broadcasting`.

A (3,) can be added to the (2,3) - that's same as adding a (1,3), again by the basic rules of `broadcasting`:

```
In [135]: x+np.array([10,20,30])
Out[135]: 
array([[10, 21, 32],
       [13, 24, 35]])
```

https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.broadcasting.html